# Bebé: ¿de qué género es?

Tags: género

Para mí la palabra **bebé** siempre ha sido gramaticalmente masculino, sea niño o niña.  Así, de hecho, lo recoge el DLE (énfasis mío)

> **1.** *m.* Niño **o niña** recién nacido o de muy corta edad.

No obstante, en el libro que usamos en mi universidad para enseñar el idioma, en varias actividades hay frases de tipo

> Laura cuida a *la* bebé.
>   *La* bebé necesita comida.
>   El padre ama a *la* bebé.

Para mí, estas frases son completamente incorrectas, precisando cada una del artículo masculino *el*, aun si el bebé es una niña, ya que es un epiceno masculino.  Obviamente, en algún lugar, parece que alguien debe considerarlo común en género (como *estudiante* que varía libremente entre géneros sin modificación).

Entonces la pregunta… ¿de qué genero es *bebé*? ¿Lo tiene correcto o no el DLE?  Y si hay diferencias geográficas o dialectales, ¿cuáles son?

Comment: Estoy contigo, no me gusta *la bebé*.  La alternativa en México por lo menos sería *la nena*.  También se dice much *la criatura*, no sé si en otros países también se dice tanto *la criatura*.  (*La criatura* es para bebés varonitos también.)

Comment: (Excuse me for writing English, my Spanish is not good enough). I understand from this article from FundeuRAE, which looks quite authoritative, that la bebé is valid in contemporary Spanish even though traditional dictionaries regard the word as masculine. https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/bebe-sustantivo-de-genero-comun/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aunque el DLE recoge  *bebé* como masculino, el [**DPD**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=beb%C3%A9) recoge tanto ***bebé*** como ***bebe*** (negritas mías):

> 2. **En España**, bebé funciona generalmente como **sustantivo epiceno masculino** (→ [género<sup>2</sup>](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Tr5x8MFOuD6DVTlDBg), [1b](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Tr5x8MFOuD6DVTlDBg#1b)):
>
> > *«En la mochila de Carolina apareció un bebé muerto. La niña era de Carolina»* (Mundo [Esp.] 20.11.96);
>
> **en América**, salvo en los países del Río de la Plata (→ [3](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=beb%E9#3)), tanto la forma aguda como la llana **se usan a menudo como sustantivos comunes en cuanto al género** (→ [género<sup>2</sup>](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Tr5x8MFOuD6DVTlDBg), [1a](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Tr5x8MFOuD6DVTlDBg#1a)):
>
> > *«Dijo que **la bebé** estaba viva»* (Tiempo [Col.] 16.11.94);
> >
> > *«Tanto la madre como **la bebe** fueron trasladadas al hospital»* (DAméricas [EE. UU.] 14.4.97).

Por tanto, parece que en América sí es correcto (o al menos usual) la forma **la bebé**

Según comenta @blonfu, en el Diccionario de Americanismos la palabra *llana* tiene **los dos géneros con diferente terminación: bebe y beba**.

Comment: En ese mismo artículo también aparece la palabra como llana: bebe. Buscando en el diccionario de americanismos la palabra llana tiene los dos géneros con diferente terminación: bebe y beba.

Comment: @blonfu: en el DLE también figura sin tilde, aunque no lo he resaltado. Incorporo tu comentario a la respuesta

Comment: "En la mochila de Carolina apareció un bebé muerto." que clase de ejemplo es ese? madre mia :o

Comment: Carolina se ha metido en un buen problema...

Answer (score 5):

Como complemento a lo respondido más arriba con base al DPD, una nota sobre la región rioplatense. Por estos lados *el bebé* refiere siempre a un varón; el femenino es *la bebé* o, más comúnmente, *la beba*. Los diminutivos son *bebito* y *bebita*. En base a lo que se ve en medios de prensa, esto parece ser así tanto en Argentina como en Uruguay y Paraguay.

Aunque no tengo una fuente, añadiría que la forma *bebe* (acentuación llana o grave) es una innovación. Existe en el habla porteña (de la ciudad de Buenos Aires), asociada al registro de la clase media-alta, pero no más al interior de la región (por ejemplo, en Rosario, a 300 km de Buenos Aires) ni tampoco del otro lado del río, en Montevideo. De hecho, la primera vez que la vi en un diario en línea pensé que se trataba de un error tipográfico; hasta el día de hoy los medios porteños emplean ambas formas sin criterio claro.

Comment: En Colombia es casi igual _el bebé y la bebé_ son las formas comunes, sin embargo una _beba_ nunca lo he oído.